# Using LWP::UserAgent to retrieve MRTG Graph in Perl

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent, mrtg

I am trying to retrieve an MRTG graph using Perl in Linux environment .

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);

my $response = $ua->get('http://www.myview.internetaccess.tatacommunications.com/cgi-bin/');


if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

I used the code , but got the following error :-

```
  Error:   401 Authorization Required at mrtg.pl line 18.
```

Then I added  this to the code  ,

```
$ua->credentials("url","username","password");
```

But I get the same error . 
Can anyone please help me fix it . 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) again, you're missing a parameter:

> $ua->credentials( $netloc, $realm, $uname, $pass )
>
> Get/set the user name and password to be used for a realm.
>
> The $netloc is a string of the form "<host>:<port>". The username and password will only be passed to this server. Example:
>
> $ua->credentials("www.example.com:80", "Some Realm", "foo", "secret");

Probably an easier method would be just to include the u/p in the url.

```
my $response = $ua->get('http://user:pass@www.myview.internetaccess.tatacommunications.com/cgi-bin/');
```

Comment: what is a realm in this context?

Comment: Honestly, don't know.  That's another reason why i suggested an alternative solution.

Comment: The realm is the identifier provided by the server when asking for a user/password.  In Apache, it is the "AuthName" configuration parameter.  
If you don't know what the Realm is, or if it changes, then your only way around it is to define a superclass of LWP:UserAgent and override get_basic_credentials to return the credentials you want regardless of the $realm parameter.  Then use this LWP::MyUserAgent instead.